# URL rewrites for two URLs won't work correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following URLS which I need to rewrite:
product.php?iata=TV&product=12345
to
product/Televison/TV/Sony-Bravia/12345

and

product-list.php?iata=TV
to
product-list/Television/TV

I have the following rewrite rules in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule [^/]+/([A-Za-z]+)/[^/]+/([0-9]+) product.php?iata=$1&product=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule [^/]+/([A-Za-z]+) product-list.php?iata=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

but they don't work correctly. Please can anyone help.

Also, what if product-list.php also had two query vars? Would the rule conflict with the rule of product.php?

Thanks

Comment: Where did the "Sony-Bravia" come out of in the first example? :-)

Comment: @LiorCohen these doesn't seem to be dynamic rules for rewrite though, more like static ones

Comment: @davogotland: yeah, I suppose, it's just that his example is misleading.

Comment: HI guys, thanks for the reply. The actual product names don't really matter as it is only the TV and the 12345 that is needed. So in essence, it could be product/PeterPan/TV/Hook/12345 and it would still work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ product.php?iata=$2&product=$4 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^product-list/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ product-list.php?iata=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Tell me if it works

---

### Two hints:

If you're not in a hosted environment (= if it's your own server and you can modify the virtual hosts, not only the `.htaccess` files), try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Olivier. What if product-list also had two query vars? Would that creat a conflict? How would the rule know which page to serve?

Comment: That would never create a conflit because each rewriterule handle different URLs. Update your question accordingly, and I'd be glad to update my answer accordingly too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^product-list/[^/]+/(.*)$ product-list.php?iata=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^product/[^/]+/([^/]+)/[^/]+/(.*)$ product.php?iata=$1&product=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```